# How to wrap 2 'if' so it is printed in one row? Example provided

Tags: php, reactjs

Below two func pulling basic fields from dbase. I need to put this two vars so it is printed in one row. How to wrap it?

```
if($accountModel->get('paidrestaurant')) {
    $html .= "<table> <tr style='height:6px; line-height:3px; color: #bbbbbb'> <td style='vertical-align: middle;'> <p style='text-align:left; vertical-align:middle;'></p> </td> 
    <td style='vertical-align: middle;'> <p style='font-size: 6px; color: red;'>Restaurant | {$accountModel->get('')}</p></td>
    </tr> </table>";
}

if($accountModel->get('refrigerator')) {
    $html .= "<table> <tr style='height:6px; line-height:3px; color: #bbbbbb'> <td style='vertical-align: middle;'> <p style='text-align:left; vertical-align:middle;'></p> </td> 
    <td style='vertical-align: middle;'> <p style='font-size: 6px; color: red;'>Refrigerator | {$accountModel->get('')}</p></td>
    </tr> </table>";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

test this code

```
$html .= "<table> <tr style='height:6px; line-height:3px; color: #bbbbbb'>";

if($accountModel->get('paidrestaurant')) {
   $html .= " <td style='vertical-align: middle;'> <p style='text-align:left; vertical-align:middle;'></p> </td> 
    <td style='vertical-align: middle;'> <p style='font-size: 6px; color: red;'>Restaurant | {$accountModel->get('')}</p></td>";
   
}

if($accountModel->get('refrigerator')) {
    $html .= " <td style='vertical-align: middle;'> <p style='text-align:left; vertical-align:middle;'></p> </td> 
    <td style='vertical-align: middle;'> <p style='font-size: 6px; color: red;'>Refrigerator | {$accountModel->get('')}</p></td>  ";
}

$html .= "</tr> </table>";
```